# .NetCore HttpClient adds unnecessary items to Accept-Encoding

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to migrate a project to .Net Core and I had an implementation using HttpWebRequest. Now on .Net Core I managed to change the code but when I was inspecting the raw requests via Fiddler my Accept-Encoding was

```
Accept-Encoding: identity, gzip, deflate
```

instead of

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

I tried resetting the header, to remove them, but they don't exist on the client nor request before I call

```
client.SendAsync(request);
```

If for some reason these can't be fixed due to a limitation is there a way to create raw HTTP requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression` is adding the header.When you turn off automatic decompression, it will leave the 'Accept-Encoding' headers blank.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.None;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var result = client.GetStringAsync("http://headers.cloxy.net/request.php");
```

Verified by Fiddler:

```
GET http://headers.cloxy.net/request.php HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: headers.cloxy.net
```

One interesting fact is that my ISP forces my traffic via a transparent proxy, and no matter how my request is, the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` is always received by the other end.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer. But i actually scratched the project and went with Mono instead using TCP Socket for better control. .Net Core lacks a lot in the implementation of TCP Sockets at the moment.